# How implement Boolean convertor When reading CSV file using CSVHelper libraries

Tags: c#, csvhelper

My CSV file has values of YES, NO, True, and False (OR) empty.
Do we have any option to convert bool from Yes, No, False, True, or empty in the latest version of CSVhelper libraries? (OR) need to implement any converter?

```
sample data:

ACCOUNTID,IsValid
1,yes
2,True
3,No
4,
5,false
```

Comment: Thank you. I will implement bool convertor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `BooleanTrueValues` and `BooleanFalseValues` attributes.

Looks like you can just add the attributes to the IsValid property

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes/

e.g.:

```
public class CsvData
{
    public int AccountId{ get; set; }

    [BooleanTrueValues("yes", "True")]
    [BooleanFalseValues("no", "False")]
    public bool IsValid{ get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.Is this works for "YES, NO, empty" values?. Let me check

Comment: I would think you can add as many values as you want. But maybe at that point it's better to write a boolconverter.

[BooleanFalseValues("no", "NO", "No", "False", "false", "")]